# Handling post requests in express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to use the value given in the a form in Node.js.

Here is the example :

```
index.html : 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 


<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div align="middle"  >
        <!--Ethernet 1 Tab -->
        <form method="POST" action="firstName">
        <p align="left">first name  </br> <input align="middle" name="firstName" placeholder="firstname" id="firstname" ></p> 

        <p align="left"> second name </br>   <input align="middle"   name="secondname" placeholder="second name" ></p>  
      </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" >

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app  = express()
var path = require('path')


app.use(express.urlencoded())
console.log(__dirname)

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'))

})
app.post('/firstName', (req, res) => {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName
  console.log(firstName)
})
app.listen(3002);
```

Well I was hoping to see anything on the console but nothing.
I am new to the Node.js. I don't get what I am missing.

Comment: You have some errors in your HTML that you need to fix: https://validator.nu

Comment: Place the submit button inside the form

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: The self-closing br tag is `<br/>`, not `</br>`.

Comment: Since it isn't XHTML, there's no point in using XML syntax anyway, so just `<br>` is fine … although hard line breaks used for styling purposes aren't greate. Better to use `display: block` on the `<label>` element that the OP should be using.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for replying, change the position of the button solved it and it works, if you put as answer I'll accept it

Comment: @Engine — It's just a typo. Deleting the question would be a better bet.

Answer (score 2):

On Express version 4.16+, body parser comes by default, so just move your `input type="submit"` within your form tag to work.

Or else you'll need body-parser package

post values can be accessed through body parser, so you need to include body parser package in your code and then values can be accessed from `req.body.firstName`

Body Parser Initialization

add this

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

before

```
const app  = express()
```

then before `app.use()` add

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

Edit: Also move your `input type="submit"` within your form tag to work.

Comment: OP also needs to move the submit button inside the `<form>`.

Comment: yes but to access values he would still need body parser

Comment: I tought theat the body parser was for older express version ?

Comment: @sid body-parser was added back in express. No need of that afaik

Comment: They have a body parser: `app.use(express.urlencoded())`

Comment: if he's on older version then he might need it